# Add number to variable's name

Tags: java, android

I have editTexts siteName1, siteName2, siteName3, siteURL1, siteURL2, siteURL3 and buttons - clear1, clear2, clear2.

When clear1 is pressed, siteName1 and siteURL1 are cleared.
When clear2 is pressed, sitename2 and siteURL2 are cleared, you got the idea.

I created onClickListener for buttons and function clear.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.clear1:
            clear(1);
            break;
        case R.id.clear2:
            clear(2);
            break;
        case R.id.clear3:
            clear(2);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

and function

```
void clear(int i){
            siteName1.getText().clear();
            siteURL1.getText().clear();
        }
```

I want to make one function for all 3 buttons. Is there any way to make something like this

siteName + i.getText().clear(); ? So I don't need to create 3 seperate functions just for clearing editTexts. Thanks.

Comment: Don't. Just use arrays (or appropriate collections). Also, it seems ‘site’ should be wrapped in a class that does all this.

Comment: can you post your html code?

Comment: You can via reflection, but I would not do that for your problem.. maybe use a method that simply takes the objects for you ui elements as parameters. and call it like `clear(siteName1, siteUrl1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider creating an array of your variables.

```
EditText siteName[] = new EditText[3];
```

Then, you can refer to each of them as siteName[0], siteName[1] and siteName[2]. Similarly for siteURL and clear buttons.

> Is there any way to make something like this siteName + i.getText().clear(); ?

This would then be `siteName[i].getText().clear();`

Answer (score 0):

Save all the sited in a `HashMap<Int, View>` and when you call `clear(int i)` you `iterate` through the `map` for the correct site

Answer (score 0):

create a hash map of hashmap
add buttons and corresponding textviews in the hashmap

then do something like this:

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
  //pass the button view to clear function
  clear(v);    
}

void clear(View view){
   viewsHashMap.get(view).getText().clear();      
}
```

I hope this should solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Put your siteName and siteURL in tables.

```
ArrayList<EditText> siteaNames= new ArrayList();
ArrayList<EditText> siteURLS= new ArrayList();
```

then put the edittexts on each list.

then depending on what int you pass to your function clear the element in the nth possition of your lists.

```
void clear(int i){
           ((EditText) siteNames.get(i)).setText("");   
           ((EditText) siteURLS.get(i)).setText("");
        }
```